# Passing an argument to a method defined inside a method in Java

Tags: java, methods, abstract, overriding

So the situation is something like this:

```
private void myMethod()
{
    System.out.println("Hello World"); //some code

    System.out.println("Some Other Stuff"); 

    System.out.println("Hello World"); //the same code. 

}
```

We don't want to be repeating our code.

The technique described [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t373066-why-i-cannot-have-a-method-inside-another-method.html) works pretty well:

```
private void myMethod()
{
    final Runnable innerMethod = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World"); 
        }
    };

    innerMethod.run();
    System.out.println("Some other stuff"); 
    innerMethod.run(); 
}
```

But what if I want to pass in a parameter to that inner method?

eg.

```
private void myMethod()
{
    final Runnable innerMethod = new Runnable()
    {

        public void run(int value)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World" + Integer.toString(value)); 
        }
    };

    innerMethod.run(1);
    System.out.println("Some other stuff"); 
    innerMethod.run(2); 
}
```

gives me: `The type new Runnable(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Runnable.run()`

While

```
private void myMethod()
{
    final Runnable innerMethod = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        public void run(int value)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World" + Integer.toString(value)); 
        }
    };

    innerMethod.run(1);
    System.out.println("Some other stuff"); 
    innerMethod.run(2); 
}
```

gives me `The method run() in the type Runnable is not applicable for the arguments (int)`.

Comment: Okay, it's not at all clear to me why this involves runnables and presumably multithreading - can you clarify that?

Comment: Are you aware that `Runnable` is a pre-defined interface used for `multithreading`? Why don't you create your own interface?

Comment: It's the only solution I've found to do a method in method in Java.

Comment: But why you want a method in method?

Comment: Runnable wasn't designed for this purpose (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Did you try defining your own interface instead of using Runnable ? This way you'll have all the latitude you need.

Comment: The return type of run method in the Runnable is void, so you cant pass arguments to it. You have to find a different way to make the argument available to it.

Comment: @RohitJain because I've got code the repeats within the method, that isn't used anywhere outside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just want inner methods. Java does't let you have them, so the `Runnable` hack you describe lets you sort-of declare an inner method.

But since you want more control over it, why not define your own:

```
interface Inner<A, B> {
    public B apply(A a);
}
```

Then you can say:

```
private void myMethod(..){ 
    final Inner<Integer, Integer> inner = new Inner<Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer apply(Integer i) {
            // whatever you want
        }
    };


    // then go:
    inner.apply(1);
    inner.apply(2);
```

}

Or use some library that provides `functor` objects. There should be many. Apache Commons has a Functor that you can use.

Comment: `public B apply(a A);` - is this a typo? you mean `public B apply (A a)`?

Also - I think you are missing something with the implementation - with code as it is gives me 

`The type new InnerMethod(){} must implement the inherited abstract method InnerMethod.apply(Object)`

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I should have marked it as untested code. Fixed now.

Comment: Hmm - how I would I write it if I wanted to create a void method? (Or pass in a void parameter?).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, that isn't a method but an anonymous object. You can create an extra method to use for the object.

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(  new Runnable()
    {
      int i,j;
      public void init(int i, int j)
      {
        this.i = i;
        this.j=j;
      }
    });
thread.init(2,3);
thread.start();
```

And wrap runnable in a Thread, and call start! Not `run()`.
Because you can't call the constructor of an anonymous class, as pointed out by @HoverCraft you could extend a named class that implements `Runnable`.

```
public class SomeClass implements Runnable
{
   public SomeClass(int i){ }
}
```

Comment: Or use a non-anonymous class with a constructor that takes the parameter values of interest.

Comment: It works but I'm not sure it helps the OP in the long term. Using Thread / Runnable for this purpose just feels terribly wrong, not to mention the side-effects start() can produce.

Comment: @Jerome Unfortunately the OP doesn't explain why he or she wants it that way.